# Using domain instead of IP in haproxy backend

Tags: networking, haproxy

I have 2 virtual host

app.example.com:80 on ip address `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

app2.example.com:80 on ip address `yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy`

my haproxy ipaddress is `sss.sss.sss.sss`

This is haproxy configuration :

```
global
   log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
   maxconn 2000
   user haproxy
   group haproxy

defaults
  log     global
  mode    http
  option  httplog
  option  dontlognull
  retries 3
  option redispatch
  timeout connect  5000
  timeout client  10000
  timeout server  10000

frontend www-http
    mode http
    bind *:80
    default_backend appname
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    stats auth admin:password
    stats show-node

backend appname
  balance roundrobin
  option httpclose
  option forwardfor
  server lamp1 app.example.com:80 check
  server lamp2 app2.example.com:80 check
```

When trying to access using haproxy ipaddress, web browser returns xampp dashboard instead of backend content.

How can i make haproxy to redirect to backend content?

Comment: In the backend, add `http-request set-header Host app.example.com` perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

I do believe that functionality is now available in 1.6,
http://blog.haproxy.com/2015/10/14/whats-new-in-haproxy-1-6/

what you have configured will simply loadbalance the request between those to instances :

```
server lamp1 app.example.com:80 check
server lamp2 app2.example.com:80 check
```

if they are 2 seperate apps rather try:

```
frontend www-http
mode http
bind sss.sss.sss.sss:80
stats enable
stats uri /haproxy?stats
stats auth admin:password
stats show-node

acl app01 hdr(Host) -i app.example.com
acl app02 hdr(Host) -i app02.example.com

use_backend app01 if app01
use_backend app02 if app02

backend app01
balance roundrobin
option httpclose
option forwardfor
server lamp1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 check

backend app02
balance roundrobin
option httpclose
option forwardfor
server lamp2 yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:80 check
```

If you now hit your haproxy with app.example.com you will be forwarded to lamp1 and app2.example.com will take you to lamp2

if you want to forward everything to the ip to the backend and dont care for extra matching and mapping then id use a straight listen, instead of a frontend :

```
 listen SOMENAME sss.sss.sss.sss:80
 balance leastconn
 mode http
 server lamp1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
 server lamp2 yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:80
```

Comment: I mean if I hit using sss.sss.sss.sss, how do I forward the connection to the backends?

Comment: ive updated my answer, see the last part of the post, hope it helps

Comment: Note that simply swapping out IP for hostname will not make `haproxy` respond to DNS changes. The DNS query will be done once, and remain static. To make `haproxy` send DNS probes and update its mapping table regularly, you need to add the `resolvers` section and keyword. For example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61655830).

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly, "default_backend" expects to have "backend" value as an attribute, not "listen".

https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-default_backend

So i suggest changing to

```
backend appname
  balance roundrobin
  option httpclose
  option forwardfor
  server lamp1 app.example.com:80 check
  server lamp2 app2.example.com:80 check
```